# Math result should be zero but is slightly off compared to direct substitution

Tags: python

Update: Thanks guys, I didn't realize it was very close to zero but not exactly zero.  Is there a way around it so my program sees it as a zero?  Its throwing my results off because this value is not being picked up as a zero.
Update2: figured it out, adding:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 6
```

and then Decimal(number) fixed it.Thanks everyone!

I am running a simple piece of code but was getting a weird result with a specific number.  Its a bit strange because when I run the same command in the python terminal I get the result I expect.

I made the print statement, the command its running so I could copy/paste it in the interpreter(python 2.7) to see if the results are the same. Here's the program:

```
x = 20
for s in range(100 + 1): 
    for c in range(100+1):
        if s == 7:
            print s, '-', (c*0.01), '*', x, ' = ', (s - (c*0.01) * x)
```

The results look fine except one:

```
7 - 0.33 * 20  =  0.4
7 - 0.34 * 20  =  0.2
7 - 0.35 * 20  =  -8.881784197e-16
7 - 0.36 * 20  =  -0.2
7 - 0.37 * 20  =  -0.4
```

When I copy/paste `7 - 0.35 * 20` into the interpreter I get 0.0 which is what I would expect(the other results in the program seem fine, except 7 - 0.35 * 20 and(not shown) a similar value with 14.

I'm a bit stumped, I'm not what's going on here.

Comment: It is called an *interpreter*, not an interrupter. =)

Comment: @ninjagecko sorry, safari autocorrected me :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between the output of the interactive interpreter and your program, but you're giving it different input. Observe:

```
>>> print 7 - 0.35 * 20
0.0
>>> print 7 - 35 * 0.01 * 20
-8.881784197e-16
```

And that, as others have already noted, is due to roundoff error.

Comment: Is there a way I can fix this in my program?  Basically I'm checking for 0 but -8.881784197e-16 is not being seen as 0 by my if statement.

Comment: @learningJava your "fix" isn't really a fix -- you're just rounding to six decimal places. There isn't anything to fix, because this isn't a bug!

Answer (score 4):

> Unfortunately, most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as
>   binary fractions. A consequence is that, in general, the decimal
>   floating-point numbers you enter are only approximated by the binary
>   floating-point numbers actually stored in the machine.

[Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Answer (score 3):

You've discovered the inexact nature of (IEEE 754) floating-point math.  You are computing a result very close to zero, but it is not exactly zero because microprocessors commonly do floating-point math in a way which sacrifices some precision for other nice things like speed and compact storage.

How this very-close-to-zero value is printed may depend on which version of Python you are using non-interactively (is that also 2.7?).

Answer (score 2):

You should decide how close to zero you would like your number to be, and then check that.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> is_float_zero = lambda x, eps=np.finfo(float).eps: np.abs(x) < eps
>>> is_float_zero(1e-10)
False
>>> is_float_zero(1e-20)
True
```

`eps` is the precision of a float. You will want to increase this depending on how much processing you are doing on the number. Note by the way that setting decimal precision to 6 throws away a lot of accuracy!

Answer (score 1):

`-8.881784197e-16` (-8.8 * 10^(-16)) is very very very close to 0. You are experiencing float precision error.

This is because you are not really doing `7 - 0.35 * 20` like you think you are. You are printing 35*0.01 which looks like 0.35, but is not.

```
>>> 7 - (0.35 * 20)
0

>>> 7 - (35*0.01 * 20)
-8.881784197001252e-16

>>> 35*0.01
0.35000000000000003
```